# Cython: Let python create memory to be filled by C++

Tags: python, c++, pointers, cython

I have a C++ layer of code that receives messages through UDP and decodes this messages into a C-struct. I want to pass this message info on to the application layer on top of this message layer. The application layer is written in Python and we use Cython to bridge between Python and C++. 
The basic idea is to have Python register to callback functions:

1. To create a storage area for the C-struct. Since Python will be using the C-struct in its application we want to make the application layer responsible for creating the actual memory. When the C++ layer calls this callback function it should return the pointer to the storage area of the C structs.
2. To signal to the Python application that the storage area of the C-struct (created in function 1) is filled with the data of the received message.

The issues I am struggling with are:

1. How to return the pointer to the C-struct as created by Python, properly to the C++ layer?
2. Should I call Py_IncRef on the pointer when receiving it and Py_DecRef on the pointer when signalling to python the storage area of the pointer is now filled with data?

The help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm reluctant to post a full answer (because it's both pretty involved, and I'm not sure what you're after). A few points: 1) callback functions to be called from C/C++ are very tricky (if you want to use Python functions - they're OK with pure Cython functions I think); 2) Allocating the memory in Python/Cython is easy - follow this example, http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#create-cython-wrapper-class; 3) You don't want to call `Py_Inc/DecRef` in C++, but you do want to think about the lifetime of the wrapper object.

Answer (score 2):

For exchanging data between c++ and cython, I would arrange the data to fit one of the existing proof of concepts on this, like Numpy.

Please see this discussion.
http://scipy-user.10969.n7.nabble.com/Share-memory-between-python-an-C-td11811.html

and especially pay attention to this:
http://gael-varoquaux.info/programming/cython-example-of-exposing-c-computed-arrays-in-python-without-data-copies.html?p=157

Or I would altogether use a standardized framework for communicating in shared memory between languages (even though that do waste some time serializing and deserializing)
In this case, I would probably use protobuf (google code) or similar.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protocyt/0.1.5